Double slit experiment: why is there uncertainty as to which slit an electron/photon goes through?
In constructing a double slit experiment, why is there some uncertainty as to which slit an electron fired, one-at-a-time, will enter? I can imagine this with a light ray, where the ray itself is wider than the distance between the slits, but for a single electron, or a single photon, why is there uncertainty as to which slit it will enter? Is each photon/electron fired in a random direction? Or are they all fired in the same direction, but it has something to do with the distance from the source to the slits?

Yes in the DSE the electron beam covers both slits. Yes it is random, when an atom releases a photon or electron we never know precisely when or in what precise direction until we measure it.

Quantum mechanics theory says that an electron has a wave function. Strictly saying there is no exact electron position. When there is a wave function similarly to electromagnetic field there is a diffraction of the electron on the both slits.
If the wave packet size is smaller then the distance between the slits, you can imagine that it will indeed pass the only slit and not diffract on both

The electron, pre-measurement (i.e. pre-collapse), has an uncertainty in it's position because it's properties are determined by the wave function, a probability wave. as long as that wavefunction is non-zero in both of the slits, there will be some amount of interference. Of course, the clarity of that interference will depend the distance between the two slits and the distance of the source from the slits, because the wavefunction is initially localized near the source and spreads from there.
You say you understand the argument for a light ray, but the point is that this argument works even for single photons. They themselves are EM waves and, supposing we fire them one at a time, nothing relevant would change in what I said.

Perhaps it's not as instructive asking about electrons and photons. My question is more, why does the double slit subvert one's expectations? But we need to know what to expect in the first place. Maybe it's more historical. Prior to the development of quantum mechanics, what did physicists believe they were doing by firing a single electron through at a double slit? The wave function formalism wasn't formulated at that point, was it?

Feynman describes the experiment with bullets, and what one would expect in terms of a distribution. Perhaps with hindsight, it's not an apt comparison because bullets are not electrons, but let's take that example. How does one arrange an experiment where the bullets enter the slits randomly? And then, how was this done for electrons? Physicists must have thought they were doing something like this at the time?

No, they based they opinion on the particle theory. Which did not turned out for double slit experiment

You might consider a distribution of particles directions.

but the interference of wave will not appear

there are interference peaks that cannont be explained just by direction distribution

I'm not sure if I understand your last two comments. The interference pattern emerges (for electrons) when fired one-at-a-time. Let's forget the electrons for a moment though. If we were to take Feynman's example of bullets, how would one construct a double slit experiment such that there is some normal looking density on the screen, centered between the two slits, which is what you "should expect"? How would you incorporate some randomness into which slit/angle it went?

Suppose the slits have some width, such that there is a range of firing angles $\Delta \theta$ which will allow the bullets to path through the slit, one range for each slit $\Delta \theta_1$ and $\Delta \theta_2$. Pick some distribution of the angles; totally random (i.e. flat distribution of angles), or Gaussian, or whatever. you will not get an interference pattern. Instead, the trajectories will on average clump up near the center of the path through each slit.
In particular, there are areas on the board that are impossible to reach with a classical trajectory (like between the slits).

imagine that you launch a bullets from the same locations with an angle distribution, this is a first problem. And another is shooting a plane wave to the slits. The result is not the same

I do not know if you mean the following, but imagine you launch particles to a slit. They have a statistical distribution of angles. So, on the screen you get a distribution "cut" by a slit. However if you shoot a "probability" wave, lets say a plane wave, the resulting distribution at the the screen far away will be a Fourier transform of the incoming field. Thus, the results are not the same.

The questions about the uncertainty of particles at slits will continue indefinitely as long as this is taught with the phenomenon of interference. As is well known, interference involves the summation of energy states, including the completely destructive state. But this is exactly what happens neither for electrons nor for photons. The mathematical construct of interference is a very suitable tool for calculating the intensity distribution behind edges, but - if left uncommented - it provides the basis for these ever-repeated questions about uncertainty.
There is an experiment from 1913 by W. Arkadiev that was repeated by H. Boersch (see this excerpt). The intensity distribution of electrons behind an edge is investigated. 1940 H. Boersch published his paper “FRESNELSCHE Elektronenbeugung”. Hans Boersch recalls that image records of the FRAUNHOFER deflection phenomenon for electrons was published first in 1913 by W. Arkadiev in Phys. Z. 14, p. 832 (1913).

So the first thing we note is the fact that you don't need slits to observe a wavelike intensity distribution. The phenomenon occurs behind every edge.

In 1956 G. Möllenstedt und H. Düker published "Beobachtungen und Messungen an Biprisma-lnterferenzen mit Elektronenwellen". 1 (Observations and measurements on biprism interferences with electron waves). wire  By applying a positive voltage of only a few volts on the filamentary center plate, the electrons of the two partial beams are bent towards the center (see the same excerpt). For the - opposite to light 105 times smaller cross section of the electron - a potential of +7 volts was enough for a successfully diffraction of electrons.

Thus we note that the application of an electric potential to an edge influences the intensity distribution. More generally, the edge - or the surface electrons of the edge - interacts with the particle beam.

The theoretical basis for describing phononic processes, in which the supply of energy to a material leads to vibrations within the material, has existed for many years. The passing of a particle is just such a borrowed energy input. If the description can be based on discrete variables (kinetic energy, quantized spin influence as in the Stern-Gerlach experiment), then the intensity distribution can be explained, including new possibilities for focusing the beam through metamaterials. A kind of the stealth technology for lower edge deflections.
